# Problem connecting botium to lex through git bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, git-bash, amazon-lex, botium-box

I am trying to connect botium to my lex bot through git bash. My botium.json looks something like this

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "My Bot Test",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "lex",
      "LEX_REGION": "us-east-1",
      "LEX_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "mykeyID",
      "LEX_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "mysecretaccesskey",
      "LEX_PROJECT_NAME": "myBotName",
      "LEX_PROJECT_ALIAS": "myBotNameAlias"
    },
    "Sources": {},
    "Envs": {}
  }
}
```

I try to run the following command
`botium-cli nlpextract --config botium.json --convos /output --verbose`

and it gives me this error

```
2020-03-11T00:03:23.566Z botium-BotDriver Loaded Botium configuration file ./botium.json
2020-03-11T00:03:23.567Z botium-BotDriver Loaded Botium configuration file botium.json
2020-03-11T00:03:23.568Z botium-BotDriver Changed capability CONFIG to "botium.json" using environment variables.
2020-03-11T00:03:25.157Z botium-BotDriver Loaded Botium configuration file ./botium.json
2020-03-11T00:03:25.157Z botium-BotDriver Loaded Botium configuration file botium.json
2020-03-11T00:03:25.158Z botium-BotDriver Changed capability CONFIG to "botium.json" using environment variables.
Failed to extract utterances: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.5.205.58:443
```

This doesn't seem like the right IP, but I don't know how to set the connection. When I run the commands, I am already logged in to my AWS CLI account through git bash, so, I assumed it should connect right away. But the connection always times out. Couldn't find any documentation the could help me in this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This IP belongs to amazon. The host names where Lex client connects to are not subject to configuration, but they are calculated automatically (in your case, the endpoint https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com is used - https//{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com).

It looks like the access is blocked somehow - local firewall, corporate firewall, proxy, whatever.